# Converting longitude latitude to tile coordinates

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coordinates, openstreetmap, tile

I want to get a map tile from a server by typing in the longitude and latitude.
Since map tiles are arranged like a grid, i need to convert my longitude and latitude to an x and y position.

The algorithm is explained here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_.28JavaScript.2FActionScript.2C_etc..29

I correctly implemented this algorithm, but unfortunately these are not the correct coordinates for the tileservers.
As you can see here http://tools.geofabrik.de/map/#12/52.5106/13.3989&type=Geofabrik_Standard&grid=1
the correct tilecoordinates for Berlin are (2200, 1343) on zoomlevel 12, while the algorithm gives me (2645, 1894).

Where is the mistake in the algorithm or my misunderstanding of how this conversion works?

Comment: That geofabrik tools website is amazingly useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tilesname WebCalc](http://oms.wff.ch/calc.htm) seems to use the same code as presented on the [slippy map tilenames wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_.28JavaScript.2FActionScript.2C_etc..29) and outputs the same tile names as the Geofabrik tool. So the algorithm must be correct and the error seems to be in your implementation which you didn't show us.

Oh, I'm pretty sure you just mixed up lat and lon. If I enter the coordinates in the wrong order into Tilesname WebCalc then it also returns the "wrong" tile names given in your question. So your code is fine, you just call it the wrong way.

Comment: Oh, wow, you are right. I didn't show my implementation because it is like exactly the same as you can see on the slippy map tilenames wiki. I just did my input with the parameters the other way round. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The following code is takes lng, lat & zoom and return X & Y values and Z is the zoom. you need to put it in url and voila you get the tile

```
const  EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137;
const  MAX_LATITUDE = 85.0511287798;

    function project (lat, lng)
    {
        var d = Math.PI / 180,
                max = MAX_LATITUDE,
                lat = Math.max(Math.min(max, lat), -max),
                sin = Math.sin(lat * d);
    
        return {x: EARTH_RADIUS * lng * d,
                y: EARTH_RADIUS * Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / 2
            };
    }
    
    
    function zoomScale (zoom)
    {
      return 256 * Math.pow(2, zoom);
    }
    
    
    function transform (point, scale) {
      scale = scale || 1;
      point.x = scale * (2.495320233665337e-8    * point.x + 0.5);
      point.y = scale * (-2.495320233665337e-8 * point.y + 0.5);
      return point;
    }
    
    var point1 = project (lat1, lng1);
    var scaledZoom = zoomScale (zoom);
    point1 = transform (point1, scaledZoom);
```

point1 is what you need the X & Y

Answer (score 1):

There is some codes provided @ [wiki.openstreetmap.org](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).

Usage example:

```js
const lon2tile = (lon,zoom) => (Math.floor((lon+180)/360*Math.pow(2,zoom)));
const lat2tile = (lat,zoom) => (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom)));
 
let zoom = 12,
    latitude =  48.858,
    longitude = 2.295,
    x = lon2tile(longitude, zoom),
    y = lat2tile(latitude, zoom);

console.log( 
  zoom, x, y 
)

img.src = `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${zoom}/${x}/${y}.png`
```

```html
<img id="img"></img>
```

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_(JavaScript/ActionScript,_etc.)